# Проверка уникальности пароля JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, база-данных

Хочу сделать проверку на уникальность пароля. Что бы пользователь не вводил шаблонные слова по типу

- QWERTY
- Password[1..N]
- Root
- admin
- и тд..

Делаю все на Jquery. У меня идея записать список часто встречаемых паролей в .txt файл и потом сравнивать его с веденным паролем. Подскажите как это делается. БД не использую, php тоже.

Comment: тогда сохраните их не в txt а в json файл. и при вводе сверяйтесь. если уж так приспичило это реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка уникальности пароля по файлу

```
<input type="password" value=""/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> 
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    
        var passwords;
    
        jQuery.get("vocabulary.txt", function(data) { 
             passwords = data.split(/\r?\n/); 
        }); 
    
        jQuery('input[type=password]').keyup(function() { 
            
                    var password = $(this).val(); 
                    
                    if (jQuery.inArray( password, passwords ) == -1) { 
                        console.log('Пароль '+password+' не найден');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Пароль '+password+' найден');
                    }
        }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать так, что бы при введении пароля из словаря сразу выводило ошибку (например alert).

Comment: У меня есть функция которая отслеживает ввод каждого символа. 
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
jQuery.get("vocabulary.txt", function(data) {
            var passwords = data.split(/\r?\n/);
        });
        if (!jQuery.inArray( password, passwords )) {
            alert('Пароль не найден');
        }
});
Не работает этот вариант

Comment: в Вашей функции нет значения пароля, который Вы проверяете.  var password = $(this).val();

Comment: Добавил вашу строчку, все равно не работает..

Comment: обновил в ответе код. код рабочий. проверил

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!